# Смена мест максимального и минимального элемента в массиве

Tags: массивы, c

Нужно их поменять(максимальный элемент на место минимального,а минимальный на место максимального),в повторном выводе этого массива.
Вот как этот код должен выглядеть!Всё получилось=)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{ 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
srand (time(NULL));

const int size=10;      // инициализация размера массива
int ar[size];           // инициализация массива

cout<<"Массив:            ";
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
   ar[i]=rand()%20;     //задаем рандомный массив с 10 элементами
   cout<<ar[i]<<" ";    // вывод массива
 }
 cout<<" \n";

 int min = ar[0],max = ar[0],min_index,max_index,tmp;  // инициализация переменных (мин элемента,макс.эл.,мин индекса,макс.инд.,
 //переменная для хранения значения мин.индекса)

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  // условие для нахождения мин. и макс.

    if (ar[i] < min)              // для мин.
    {
    min = ar[i];                  // мин. элемент в массиве
    min_index = i;                // индекс мин. элемента в массиве
    }

        else if  (ar[i] > max)    // для макс.
        {
        max = ar[i];              // макс. элемент в массиве
        max_index = i;            // индекс макс. элемента в массиве
        }

    tmp = ar[min_index];           // значение мин.индекса сохраняем в переменную tmp
    ar[min_index] = ar[max_index]; // макс. индекс присваиваем мин.индекс.
    ar[max_index] = tmp;           // знач.перем. tmp(мин.индекс.) присваиваем макс.индексу

    cout<<"Массив с заменной: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i]<<" ";           // вывод массива с заменой.
    }

    cout<<"\nМаксимальное: "<<max;
    cout<<"\nМинимальное: "<<min<<endl;
    cout<<"\nМаксимальный индекс: "<<max_index<<endl;
    cout<<"\nМинимальный индекс: "<<min_index<<endl;

}
```

Всем огромное спасибо!
Еще учиться и учиться)

Comment: запоминайте при поиске минимума/максимума не сами элементы, а их индексы i, а впоследствии обменяйте местами значения

Comment: спасибо большое,но как в последствии замены вывести еще раз массив?у меня не получается.Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Anton777, напишите функцию 

     void print_int_array (int a[], int size) {
        ...
     }

и вызывайте ее сколько угодно раз.

Comment: @Anton777, ну Вы хоть чуть подумайте, а уже потом пишите.

Смотрите, программы состоит из следующих логических блоков

- ввести массив в цикле

- распечатать массив, вызвав функцию

- найти в цикле индексы max и min

-переставить эти элементы

- распечатать массив, вызвав функцию

Соответсвенно этим шагам и надо (обязательно в нужный момент) инициализировать переменные.

--

Так что, ждем очередную попытку (только, пожалуйста, сопроводите ее не просьбами, а обстоятельным рассуждением (можно в комментариях в коде) **что** и главное **с какой целью Вы делаете** в том или ином месте).

Comment: @Anton777, ну вот, у самого получилось. 

Поздравляю!!!

--

Только тип `main()` с `void` на `int` поменяйте и добавьте  в начале

    #include <stdlib.h>

тогда не только в винде будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
if (ar[i] < min)
{
    min = ar[i];
    min_index = i;
}
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if (ar[i] > max)
    {
    max = ar[i];
    max_index = i;
    }
}
tmp = ar[min_index];
ar[min_index] = ar[max_index];
ar[max_index] = tmp;
```

Comment: @MDJHD, а зачем 2 цикла? И лишний проход?

    int min = ar[0], max = ar[0], min_index = 0, max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
      if (ar[i] < min) {
        min = ar[i];
        min_index = i;
      } else if (ar[i] > max) {
        max = ar[i];
        max_index = i;
      }

и все.

Comment: Никак не могу связать все воедино,чтобы второй раз вывело массив с заменой.Можно пожалуйста полный код.

Вот как должно выглядеть: http://s43.radikal.ru/i101/1406/77/7e4bf03ca07b.jpg

Comment: В этом примере 1 меняется с 19.

Comment: @Anton777, а первый раз (до обмена min с max) Вы как выводите?

Вообще-то, не бойтесь переписывать программы. 

Подумайте, сделайте еще одну попытку и если не получится, то покажите новый код (лучше в **UPDATE** вопроса) и спросите, почему происходит *вот такая штука* (описывайте что видите на экране), хотя Вы ожидали, *что будет так*.

Comment: @avp, ну два цикла у меня потому, что я просто скопировал код с вопроса и добавил недостающие операции, не вдаваясь в какие-либо оптимизации :)